# Compile errors everywhere after workspace move

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm making a webapp in Eclipse. I use to make it in my Desktop. And today I got a laptop and I've copied the workspace in my Desktop to laptop.

And after copying the workspace, I've opened my Eclipse pointing to the copied workspace. And when I opened my Java files, almost every line is red underlined .

In my desktop there was no problem with this app, It used to work fine.

When I started my Eclipse with this copied path, I though the errors were due to the jar files (I used to have jars in my desktop associated to this project).

Even after configuring my Build path, the red lines still appear.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what do you see in problem tab?

Comment: Look in the Problems view to see what the errors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild guess: The path to the JRE is wrong so the compiler does not find the Java standard library. When none of the standard library classes are found you get compile errors at almost every line.

**Solution:**

Configure the path to the JRE in the compiler settings:

*Preferences → Java → Installed JREs*

And/or configure the path to the standard library in the project settings:

*Project settings → Java Build Path → Libraries*

Edit existing entry for system library or add a new one.

Comment: Yey! That really was a long shot.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to just copy the workspace over. You want to import the project into Eclipse. You will also want to make sure that you import, and add, any external `.jar` files. To import use:

```
File > Import > Existing Project into Workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the import wizard after setting your workspace (http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm)? This is the important part. Once that's done be sure to do a clean build. If you see errors then, you might still be missing external jars that you had on your desktop.